# How to use flow's built-in definitions

Tags: flowtype

Flow has a ton of useful definitions in its 'libs' directory, but I can't figure out how to actually use them! In particular I would like to use the BOM->Response type.

Here is a direct link:
[Flow/Libs](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.46.0/lib/bom.js#L869)

**Edit: ** Figured it out, see my answer below. Leaving this up in case someone else makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In .flowconfig I had added `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-interface.js` in the `[libs]` section which overwrote the type I wanted to use.

Comment: Could you give a code sample? I have nothing in my libs section and simply using "fetch" does not work